# get value in $scope while calling http get but its getting called once client code is finished

Tags: angularjs

In controller page i.e Expense.js

```
 $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page) {

            $scope.largeLoad = todoService.initialize();
            todoService.getDataAsync();
            $scope.setPagingData($scope.largeLoad, page, pageSize);
            $scope.sortData = $scope.largeLoad;
            $scope.toDate = "";
            $scope.fromDate = "";

            //summary();


        };
```

above page is calling todoService created in services .js

```
 var methods = {

            // Give a reference to the controller for the array 
            //  we will update asyncronously


 var todos = [];

            initialize: function () {
                return todos;
            },

 getDataAsync: function () {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                // Define status code to error mapping


                $http({ 
                  method: "get", 
                  url: '/api/ExpenseWebApi/GetGridData', 
                  cache: false 
                 })
                 .success(function (largeLoad) {
                    todos.length = largeLoad.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
                        todos[i] = largeLoad[i];
                    }

                    deferred.resolve(todos);

                })
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing the data asynchronously, but the rest of your code is going to just execute.

You should refactor to do something like this:

```
todoService.getDataAsync()
.then(function(todos){
  $scope.largeLoad = todos;
  $scope.setPagingData($scope.largeLoad, page, pageSize);
  $scope.sortData = $scope.largeLoad;
  $scope.toDate = "";
  $scope.fromDate = "";
});
```

This will guarantee that your code will execute ***AFTER*** the asynchronous call has been made.

As a little code review note. You can avoid the loop for copying items into your array by first setting the length to `0` and then using `unshift` in conjunction with `apply` in order to copy the elements of one array into another.

```
var target = [];
var source = ['Josh', 'Bob', 'Larry'];

//In case target has items already
target.length = 0;    

Array.prototype.unshift.apply(target, source);

console.log(target); // ['Josh', 'Bob', 'Larry']
```

Comment: adding then after making http call will initialize scope